# Couchbase Lite View Aggregation Values are null (empty)

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to do a simple view, that takes my data and groups all of my records by a key "sortDate". I feel like i've followed all the examples, read all the documents multiple times and it just doesn't work as expected.
Here is the view code i'm creating:

```
    guard let database = database else { return }

    database.viewNamed("byDate").setMapBlock({ (doc, emit) in
        if let date = doc["sortDate"] as? String {
            emit(date, doc)
        }
    }, version: "8")


    let query = database.viewNamed("byDate").createQuery()
    query.groupLevel = 1
    query.descending = true


    do {
        let result = try query.run()
        print(result)
        while let row = result.nextRow() {
            print(row)
            print(row.value) //EMPTY
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to retrieve all documents for \(database.name) database")
    }
```

My row.value is NULL even though there are multiple records in the database, my allDocs query is returning just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a grouplevel when the key is not an array causes CBL to aggregate the results using the reduce function.  You haven't specified one, so that's why you get no results.

From the docs:

> The value property of each row will be the result of running the view's reduce function over all the rows that were aggregated; or if the view has no reduce function, there's no value. (See the View documentation for information on reduce functions.)